# Does a phrase "by itself" have to be gramatically correct

Tags: grammar

We can have sentences which are not correct in posters and we forgive them.

I made a poster and was criticized for it.

It was (and this is the full sentence)

```
Including ghost hunting after hours.
```

I was told it should be

```
Including ghost hunt after hours.
```

Both read (sound) OK to me.

Is this actually correct or are both accepted?

Comment: These are not full sentences.  **Give us more context** and we can help you construct full sentences.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, yes it is! It is the full sentence. There was content before this, which ended with a full stop. Then the line above, as is!

Comment: He just explained IT IS A HEADLINE, NOT a sentence.

Comment: @Dave, I'd expect these "sentences" to be embedded as clauses in larger sentences. In other words "Blah blah blah, including ghost-hunting after hours." That said, it's perfectly fine to break them out into sentences of their own. Either way, the second sentence is missing an article: "*a* ghost hunt...".

Comment: Dan dude - headlines are "language fragments" - NOT sentences. It's quite hard to find a headline or poster-copy that is a "whole sentence".  Note too often they are simply "labels" (like on this page, "English language and usage" up top)

Comment: @Joe, see my comment below your answer on "headlines". I don't think these are headlines, and I don't think "posters" (as in large pieces of paper with stuff printed on them) are involved.

Comment: Yes, I'm totally with you now -- sorry

Comment: @Dave I don't see how either can be regarded as a sentence as neither contains an indicative verb. 'Including' is a present participle and the whole subordinate, adjectivally, to the main clause.

Comment: @WS2 if it not a sentence, what would you call it. With no sarcasm meant at all, I can't call it a collection of strings?!

Comment: @Dave it is a clause, I suspect adjectival.

Comment: Just out of interest, what is an 'After hours ghost hunt', does it involve staying in a pub after hours and hunting ghosts and does it involve emptying bottles and glasses while searching for them?

Comment: Once you're below sentence level, 'grammaticality' becomes (I'm tempted to add 'even') less well-defined. And then there's the complication of headlinese that may be used in posters. Your critic should state the grounds for the criticism. If they're merely style considerations (and I don't see what else they could be), that would be off-topic as a point for discussion here on ELU. BUT I'd say that if you have a ghost hunt, the regular noun rather than the ing-form is far punchier. But I'd use _i/Including after-hours ghost hunt!_ (capitalised if not a smooth follow-on; italicised; silly font).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Including ghost hunting after hours.

As a phrase, this is grammatically correct (although some people, of a poetic bent, might find the repeated gerund "including...hunting" less than euphonious).

> Including ghost hunt after hours.

*Hunt* (unlike *hunting*) is a countable noun, and as such, takes an article when appearing in the singular: "Including **a** ghost hunt after hours".  Without it, the phrase comes off as [headlinese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese).

If this is just an advertisement, have you considered simply "Ghost hunting after hours!"?  (Arguably, even "after hours" is superfluous: no one goes ghost-hunting in the light of day.)

Comment: Dude I think he's saying it is FREE, INCLUDED ghost hunting after hours.  And yes, despicably, he has not clear dup if it is "one free hunt" or "endlessly free hunting".

Comment: Except I'm pretty sure "headlinese" is exactly what is needed here...

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your NEW QUESTION dude ..

**Does a phrase “by itself,” such as an advertising headline, have to be grammatically correct?**

the only meaningful answer is: it is **incredibly** well established, with literally millions of examples, that the headlines on advertising (whether 'billboards', 'magazine ads', etc) are -- observably -- usually (indeed "almost always"), simply **sentence fragments** rather than entire sentences.

So, your question **"have to be"** -- as in "SHOULD Saatchi & Saatchi ONLY USE full sentences (indeed, grammatically correct ones) for advert headlines...."

It's kind of a meaningless question.  I mean, I'm all for completely **banning** outdoor advertising, as in Sao Paolo.

**Observably** it is incredibly common - essentially, "the norm" - that poster headlines are in fact "sentence fragments".  Note too they are often very simply "labels".

(For example, the sign on a door "Exit" or "Toilet" is not a sentence - it's a label.)

Comment: +1 Joe - JUST DO IT. Think different. Challenge everything. Be your way. i'm lovin' it.

Comment: [Stupid Label Guy](http://search.dilbert.com/comic/Label%20Guy), Dilbert. Almost 20 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Both are **perfectly correct** as the headlines on posters.

I think the second one sounds a little better - also it's shorter - but the person was totally wrong to tell you it is "grammatically incorrect".

Comment: I actually think the OP meant "posting" (i.e. a comment or post in a web forum or mailing list), not "poster" (big piece of paper). The sentences definitely do not make sense as headlines (because, then, what would *including* refer back to)?

Comment: The second one is only better if there's only one ghost hunt.

Comment: Mind you.  Who the hell would post *"Including ghost hunting after hours."* on the internet? In what context? Like, on OKCupid or what?

Comment: "Come to our Halloween party! We'll have everything! Including a ghost hunt after hours!".

Comment: That would make plenty of sense on a poster, too. Just not as literally the first line (headline) of the poster.

Comment: @DanBron, no, as I clearly state, poster means poster

Comment: @Wlerin, agreed, but statistically speaking, the OP is unlikely (in this digital age) to be talking about posting bills on a lamppost.

Comment: @DAve, you mean a large piece of paper?  That you hang up on a wall?  Ok, then I'm mistaken, forgive me. That said, it has no bearing on the "correctness" of the sentences.  They're either right or wrong, irrespective of whether they're printed on paper or written in an email.

Comment: I think the downvote here is not fair! I upvoted, which means some one downvoted!

Comment: @Dave -- do you mean **AN ADVERTISING POSTER** champ?  i worked in advertising for years, we'd get drunk and not talk about stuff like this.  lol don't worry on the down votes!

Comment: @DanBron I think you underestimate how common that still is. (Posting bills on lampposts.)